# Можно ли в python указывать тип переменной?

Tags: python

Читал, почему пайтон в больших проектах не очень быстрый, пишут, что так как мы не указываем тип к примеру переменной,  компилятору приходится самому понимать что это. Так вот, есть ли возможность сразу указать ее тип? Я пробовал просто ставить ключевые слова по типу int и тд. Не сработало. Тогда я решил сделать так

```
variable = str("строка")
```

Будет ли это считаться, что я сразу указал тип, думаю нет. Если можно прошу напишите как?

Comment: str() это конвертировал то, что в скобках, в строку. str(45) и str("45") дают одно и то же.

Answer (score 5):

Вы не ускорите программу, если укажете тип переменной. Код все равно будет сначала транслироваться в байт-код, а затем интерпретироваться. Команда за командой.

Но указать его Вы всё-таки можете. Это называется аннотация типа:

```py
variable: str = "строка"
```

Ещё раз подчеркну — это никак не повлияет на скорость программы. Аннотации [игнорируются](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) средой исполнения:

> The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type
> annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type
> checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

---

Аннотации типов могут помочь разработчикам понять, что должна хранить переменная. Также они могут описывать [классы данных](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses). Некоторые фреймворки могут использовать аннотации для реализации своего функционала (например [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi)).

**P.S.:** Даже в других ЯП указание типа переменной в Вашем примере было бы бессмысленным. По строковым литералам и так можно определить, что это строка.

Answer (score 0):

Я не очент понял вопроса, но указывать тип переменной не обязательно. Это нужно только для вас, чтобы вам было легче, но программу это не ускорит.
Если хотите узнать тип переменной, то можно проверить так:

```
print (type(variable))
```

Тогла программа выведет вам тип переменной после того, как вы запустите код.